# Pandas: Compare Datetime column on Datetime arrays

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I'm learning Pandas, specially now with Datetimes. I'm searching for days a way to select rows by their Datetime column. If the Datetime column values are on a range between the array `spacex` and `clonx` values.

The two arrays:

```
clonx = array(['2019-08-14T23:32:00.000000000', '2019-08-14T23:35:00.000000000',
       '2019-08-14T23:35:00.000000000', ...,
       '2020-05-24T14:55:00.000000000', '2020-05-24T15:03:00.000000000',
       '2020-05-25T12:09:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

spacex = array(['2019-08-14T23:27:00.000000000', '2019-08-14T23:30:00.000000000',
   '2019-08-14T23:30:00.000000000', ...,
   '2020-05-24T14:50:00.000000000', '2020-05-24T14:58:00.000000000',
   '2020-05-25T12:04:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

the column:

```
    first['datim']

0      2019-08-14 23:26:00
1      2019-08-14 23:26:00

2      2019-08-14 23:27:00
3      2019-08-14 23:30:00
4      2019-08-14 23:30:00
               ...        
5101   2020-05-25 20:48:00
5102   2020-05-25 20:49:00
5103   2020-05-26 13:52:00
5104   2020-05-26 13:52:00
5105   2020-05-26 14:22:00
Name: datim, Length: 3172, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How can I get the Datetime values from column `first['datim']` that are between datetimes of `spacex` and `clonx`?

Something like this:

```
start_date = spacex[i]
end_date = clonx[i]
for i in range:
    final = (first['datim'] >= start_date) & (first['datim'] <= end_date)
result final
```

Or maybe with [beween_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) but can't find a way to make it work with arrays.

Appreciate  your time!

Comment: do you need to check this for all values in `spacex` and `clonx` or would it maybe be sufficient to use `.min` / `.max`?

Comment: Thanks for your time @MrFruppes. It has to be between the values of both arrays like: spacex[4] - clonx[4], space[5] - clonx[5],...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `apply` to add a column to your DataFrame, based on the "`datim`" datetime compared to the two arrays of datetimes.  This will not handle massive amounts of data well, but may be fine for you.  For example, this would tell you if the time was between `any` of the datetime pairs (like @Pygirl 's answer):

```
def between_any(time):
    for s,c in zip(spacex, clonx):
        if (time  >= s) and (time <= c):
            return True
    return False

df['Between Any'] = df['datim'].apply(between_any)
```

Or you could get the indices of the date pairs that the value was between:

```
def between_index(time):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(spacex)):
        if (time  >= spacex[i]) and (time <= clonx[i]):
            output.append(i)
    return output if output else np.nan

df['Between Indices'] = df['datim'].apply(between_index)
```

Or you could actually get the Timestamps that the value was between:

```
def between_values(time):
    output = []
    for s,c in zip(spacex, clonx):
        if (time  >= s) and (time <= c):
            output.append((s,c))
    return output if output else np.nan

df['Between Values'] = df['datim'].apply(between_values)
```

Here's what this looks like based on your data:

```
In[0]: df

Out[0]:
                   datim
0    2019-08-14 23:26:00
1    2019-08-14 23:26:00
2    2019-08-14 23:27:00
3    2019-08-14 23:30:00
4    2019-08-14 23:30:00
5101 2020-05-25 20:48:00
5102 2020-05-25 20:49:00
5103 2020-05-26 13:52:00
5104 2020-05-26 13:52:00
5105 2020-05-26 14:22:00

In[1]:

clonx = pd.Series(['2019-08-14T23:32:00.000000000', '2019-08-14T23:35:00.000000000','2019-08-14T23:35:00.000000000','2020-05-24T14:55:00.000000000', '2020-05-24T15:03:00.000000000','2020-05-25T12:09:00.000000000'])

spacex = pd.Series(['2019-08-14T23:27:00.000000000', '2019-08-14T23:30:00.000000000','2019-08-14T23:30:00.000000000','2020-05-24T14:50:00.000000000', '2020-05-24T14:58:00.000000000','2020-05-25T12:04:00.000000000'])

clonx = pd.to_datetime(clonx)
spacex = pd.to_datetime(spacex)

df['Between Any'] = df['datim'].apply(between_any)
df['Between Indices'] = df['datim'].apply(between_index)
df['Between Values'] = df['datim'].apply(between_values)

df

Out[1]:

                   datim  Between Any Between Indices  \
0    2019-08-14 23:26:00        False             NaN   
1    2019-08-14 23:26:00        False             NaN   
2    2019-08-14 23:27:00         True             [0]   
3    2019-08-14 23:30:00         True       [0, 1, 2]   
4    2019-08-14 23:30:00         True       [0, 1, 2]   
5101 2020-05-25 20:48:00        False             NaN   
5102 2020-05-25 20:49:00        False             NaN   
5103 2020-05-26 13:52:00        False             NaN   
5104 2020-05-26 13:52:00        False             NaN   
5105 2020-05-26 14:22:00        False             NaN   

                                         Between Values  
0                                                   NaN  
1                                                   NaN  
2          [(2019-08-14 23:27:00, 2019-08-14 23:32:00)]  
3     [(2019-08-14 23:27:00, 2019-08-14 23:32:00), (...  
4     [(2019-08-14 23:27:00, 2019-08-14 23:32:00), (...  
5101                                                NaN  
5102                                                NaN  
5103                                                NaN  
5104                                                NaN  
5105                                                NaN
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Tom (aka blackbelt Panda)! My problem is that I do have to handle big data :( Testing it on Jupyter notebook it takes quite a while... and not giving good results

Comment: Trying to figure out what this means: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

Comment: @Zaesar to speed up you can use multiprocessing. http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/ or https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter

Comment: @Zaesar The example I posted doesn't give that warning for me.  But I have run into this issue a lot; it usually means (at least) one of the lines you have may not be editing the DataFrame in the way you think.  Look into [this article](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/), it helped me

Comment: Ok, Yes!! It is working!! Wonderful. I'm so happy to meet you  :) Wish you both a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Not a better solution though:

```
datelist = []
for i in range(len(first.datim)):
    for j in range(len(clonx)):
        if (spacex[j]<=first.datim[i]) and (first.datim[i]<=clonx[j]):
            datelist.append(first.datim[i])
print(set(datelist))
```

---

```
{Timestamp('2019-08-14 23:30:00'), Timestamp('2019-08-14 23:27:00')}
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks very close to what I'm looking! But when I run it it doesn't show anything... Also, I think a return first `['datim']` would be better. Because it is a column of a row. And I want to get the rows between this time range... Anyway, to me, today you won a piece of heaven <3

Comment: may be you dataframe name was something else. It works for few samples you have given

Comment: Thank you a lot!